# Best practice for accessing Spring's Security Context

Tags: spring, web-services, security, spring-security

I am working on a application with a layered architecture:

Presentation - Service - Data Access

Many of the modules at this service layer need access the currently logged in user. Is it a good idea to have these modules directly access the security context to obtain the `UserDetails` object?

I'm thinking that if in the future modules from the Service layer need to be exposed to other application as a Web Services, getting the Security Context may not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to be more specific, but you generally shouldn't have the whole stack directly accessing authentication information. Instead, if it's an operation where using aspect-oriented method security isn't applicable, pass the user information to service layers as ordinary method parameters. Use appropriate mechanisms (such as `@AuthenticationPrincipal`) to cleanly supply authentication information to your top-level facade (Web tier or what have you).